# Was there any backstory or purpose for the Cryogenics Pods on the Normandy?

Tags: mass-effect

The Cryogenics Pods seem like a big ol' [Chekov's Gun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chekov%27s_gun) on both the [SSV Normandy](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/SSV_Normandy) and the [Normandy SR-2](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Normandy_SR-2).  However, I did not see them being used in any of the Trilogy games nor did I notice any entries in the Codex.

In fact, there's little to no mention of them even in the [Mass Effect Wiki](http://masseffect.wikia.com/) - they're not at all noted in the SSV Normandy article, and only called out as a reference point for getting to the Main Battery in the Normandy SR-2 article.

Were they just there to add fluff, or is there some actual use for or history behind them?

Answer (score 5):

That's because they aren't cryo pods, but regular sleeping pods.  While some of the officers might have a bunk, the enlisted hot bunk in the sleeping pods.  There isn't anything special about them, which is why they don't receive more description.

Comment: I believe this is incorrect.  The Mass Effect Wiki specifically calls them Cryo Pods and, though I can't check right now to confirm, I'm fairly certain that they were called so in-game as well.

Comment: Where?  Because they specifically call them sleeper pods in the [SSV Normandy article](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/SSV_Normandy#Quarters)

Comment: In the [Normandy SR-2 Article](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Normandy_SR-2#Deck_3:_Crew.27s_Quarters) under the Deck 3 section, first paragraph, last sentence.

Comment: @Iszi Given that the paragraph in question is *not* in-game text, I think it *far* more likely that someone on the wiki erroneously referred to them as cryo pods, when in fact, they are not.

Comment: @RavenDreamer The same could be said for the "sleeper pods" statement - so I fail to see your point in mentioning this.

Comment: @Iszi I don't follow - there is a codex entry that specifically mentions sleeper pods. Cryo pods are never mentioned in the codex.

Comment: @RavenDreamer Perhaps pointing to that Codex entry would be a valid answer, then?

Comment: @RavenDreamer I would also be interest in seeing this codex entry. I just looked and couldn't find an entry that mentions sleeper pods on the Normandy.

Answer (score 3):

I finally got around to starting a new play-through in Mass Effect. I made sure this was one of the things I checked out in the first game. As it turns out, these are indeed "Sleeping Pods" - not "Cryo Pods" as I had originally thought for some reason. This is most easily noticed on the map.

[image]

You can also look at one of the pods and select it to trigger a Codex entry, *"Starships: Crew Considerations"*. In this article, one of the things noted is that smaller vessels use "hot bunking" to accommodate their crew's sleep needs while conserving space. Two crew members will share a bunk, with each taking their turn to sleep during the other's work shift.

Answer (score -1):

I believe the Cryo Pods are meant to flash freeze injured people who are beyond the help of the standard medical bay. They can then be transported to a hospital.

Comment: If they *are* cryo pods, this would make sense. Do you have any examples from the games, comics or books where this occurs to back up this theory?

Comment: The only references I can find are posts on random forums, so unfortunately it's all conjecture at this point. To me it does make sense, but unfortunately I cannot give a canon answer.